# Simple poisson probability question

Tags: probability

Births at a particular hospital occur randomly at an average rate of two per hour

i) find the probability that there three births in a particular hour, ans: $\dfrac{2^3e^{-2}}{3!}$

ii) Find the probability that there are three births in a particular $30$ minute period, ans: $\dfrac{1}{6e}$

iii) Find the probability that there are three births in a particular two-hour period and that at least one of these births occurs in the first hour.

not sure how to do iii), I was thinking of finding the prob that three births occur in a particular two hour period and multiply it by the probability the births occur in the first hour, but I don't know if they are independent and it's more of a guess then anything else.

Alternatively, I was thinking that this might be the solution: $(2^2e^{-2}/2)(\frac{4}{1}e^{-4}) + (2^1e^{-1})(4^2e^{-4}/2)$  i.e. probability that 1 occurs in first hour, multiplied by probability that 2 occur in the second hour and other way round

Does anyone know how to proceed?

edit: from @did hint, I'm trying to find the probability that 3 births occur and none occured in first hour, using conditional probability, then do 1- that answer to get the required answer.

Let A = probability 3 births in a 2 hour period, B = probability no births in a given one hour period. so I believe $P(A|B) = \dfrac{2^3e^{-2}}{3!} $ same as i) and $P(B) = e^{-2}$ so using $P(A \cap B) = P(A|B)P(B) =\dfrac{2^3e^{-2}}{3!} e^{-2} $

Comment: Try first "iv) Find the probability that there are three births in a particular two-hour period and that none of these births occurs in the first hour" and deduce iii) from iv).

Comment: is that not just the same as i)?

Comment: No. Why should it?

Comment: If none occur in the first hour then we're looking for 3 occurring in a 1 hour period

Comment: True, but does not say that Prob(iv)=Prob(i), does it? Listen, I am going to stop this exchange,, at least temporarily--please think calmly about the **precise** indications I posted and let us see what happens.

Comment: @Did attempted again.

Comment: Perfect. Now compute $P(A)-P(A\cap B)$ to conclude. Once you feel you reached a full solution, you can post it as an answer and even, after a while, accept it (this is actually recommended by the guidelines of the site).

Comment: Thanks, I still have one more question, could you explain why you would do $P(A) - P(A\cap B)?$ P(A) is the probability that 3 occur in a two hour period, probability of A and B is the probability that three births occur in a 2 hour period and none in the first hour - how would subtracting give me the required answer? Can't see it.

Comment: Read again what iii) asks you to compute.

Comment: Yes of course - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let A = probability 3 births in a 2 hour period, B = probability no births in a given one hour period. so I believe $P(A|B) = \dfrac{2^3e^{-2}}{3!} $ same as i) and $P(B) = e^{-2}$ so using $P(A \cap B) = P(A|B)P(B) =\dfrac{2^3e^{-2}}{3!} e^{-2} $ Concluding with $P(A) - P(A\cap B)$.